# Are angels men or women?

Tags: malaikah

It is famous that angels are the creatures who are always praying (of Allah) ... praising ...     But I have a question about them. Factually I was wondering if angels (Malaekah) are male or female? Or they are consist of both male and female sex?

*Present Quranic verses or hadiths (traditions) for your answers, please.*

Answer (score 6):

Sexes are distinguished on the basis of copulation and reproduction. I don't think I ever came across any references suggesting that angels engage in intercourse or even have such desires. They don't reproduce.

Some verses specifically say that they are not female (their context seems to be a response to some non-Muslims claiming that angels are the sex-slaves of God). But I know of no reference that suggests that they are males.

Was there a specific reason you thought of this?

*[You can see more on this, rather lengthly, reading](https://islamqa.info/en/96306) (go directly to the bottom of the page).*

Comment: I inquired it, since based on a common rule, almost everything or actually every creatures are considered as both sexes (such as human, animals, ...) ____ Of course what you stated regarding reproduction seems to be true. God bless you, dear mate.

Comment: Neither can you prove that they don't reproduce, it's a matter of ghaib. +1 just for quoting the verse.

Comment: @azam you are absolutely right. I should have said "there are no indication, in Islam, that they can reproduce".

Comment: But the point raised by @DearMartyrSheikhNimr-Al-Nimr is a very good one, and I think the meaning of the verses mentioning "everything created in pairs" relate more to "everything on Earth", which would answer such an apparent contradiction. But I never fully investigated the question.

Comment: There is some (scientific) opinion that states that malaikat (angels) are males. However this opinion is weak, but I just to inform so that you don't get shocked when knowing this opinion. The explanation is [here](http://abul-jauzaa.blogspot.co.id/2012/10/malaikat-termasuk-laki-laki-ataukah.html) (Bahasa Indonesia unfortunately)

Answer (score 0):

Angels in Islam are believed to be creatures that do not have a gender like humans, either male or female. This belief is based on their spiritual nature and being creatures made of light.

1. **There is no statement on the gender of angels**: The Holy Qur’an and Sunnah do not directly state the gender of angels, which indicates that they are not like humans in this aspect.
2. **Qur’anic verses**: There are no Qur’anic verses that directly address the gender of angels, but the Qur’an indicates that angels are creatures that do not resemble humans in their physical or biological characteristics. For example, the Qur’an mentions how angels are created from light (Nuriya).
3. **Islamic interpretation**: Muslim scholars indicate, based on Shari'ah texts, that angels do not have a sex. They do not reproduce, eat, or drink, which are characteristics associated with living beings that have a sex.
4. **The issue of the feminization of angels**: There are verses in the Qur’an that deny the pre-Islamic belief that angels are daughters of Allah (iyaadhubillah), such as the Allah's saying: “And they made the angels who are servants of the Most Merciful females” (Al-Zukhruf: 19), and this rejects the idea that angels have a gender. Like humans.

> Sa'id ibn al-Musayyib said: "The angels, peace be upon them, are
> neither males nor females, they do not procreate, and they neither eat
> nor drink." (Rabī' al-Abrār wa Nusūṣ al-Akhyār by Zamakhsharī (1/ 308), Fatḥ al-Bārī by Ibn Ḥajar (6/ 306).

Answer (score 0):

The angels are not women. The negation of them being called females is present in the Quran at multiple places:

> وجعلوا الملائكة الذين هم عباد الرحمن إناثا أشهدوا خلقهم ستكتب شهادتهم ويسألون
>
> And they have made the angels, who are servants of the Most Merciful, females. Did they witness their creation? Their testimony will be recorded, and they will be questioned.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 43:19](https://quran.com/43/19?translations=20)</sup>

> إن الذين لا يؤمنون بالآخرة ليسمون الملائكة تسمية الأنثى
>
> Indeed, those who do not believe in the Hereafter name the angels female names
>
> <sup>— [Quran 53:27](https://quran.com/53/27?translations=20)</sup>

> أم خلقنا الملائكة إناثا وهم شاهدون
>
> Or did We create the angels as females while they were witnesses?"
>
> <sup>— [Quran 37:150](https://quran.com/37/150?translations=20)</sup>

As for being called men then this is disagreed upon. In the exegesis of the following verses:

> وبينهما حجاب وعلى الأعراف رجال يعرفون كلا بسيماهم ونادوا أصحاب الجنة أن سلام عليكم لم يدخلوها وهم يطمعون
>
> And between them will be a partition, and on [its] elevations are men who recognize all by their mark. And they call out to the companions of Paradise, "Peace be upon you." They have not [yet] entered it, but they long intensely.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 7:46](https://quran.com/7/46?translations=20)</sup>

> ونادى أصحاب الأعراف رجالا يعرفونهم بسيماهم قالوا ما أغنى عنكم جمعكم وما كنتم تستكبرون
>
> And the men on Al-A‘râf (the wall) will call unto the men whom they would recognise by their marks, saying: "Of what benefit to you were your great numbers (and hoards of wealth), and your arrogance (against Faith)?"
>
> <sup>— [Quran 7:48](https://quran.com/7/48?translations=203)</sup>

Some traditions are recorded that the ones meant here are angels, and they have been called men.

Answer (score -1):

There is no specific statement in Quran or ahadith saying that angels are genderless. However there are verses in Quransaying that Allah created all creatures in heavens and earth with two genders in general. In general means it includes angels also. The reason why Allah rebuking kuffar saying they depict angels as females is during jahiliyyah times, some Arabs used to bury living female child. "They dislike female child while they depict and worship angels of Allah as females??!! For Allah, females you depict??!! For you , you need males??!!". This is in the sense of how Allah is asking kuffar sarcastically.:).  So all creatures has genders including angels and they also live as communities. But angels are much pure creations. Having Desires is not wrong thing if it is within the boundaries of Allah's hukm.angels donot have caprice greed envy etc. Allah has set boundaries for all the creatures and He set same boundaries for humans and jinns. Humans and jinns has given temporal ability to disobey but angels can't disobey. Humans and jinns can do mistakes and sins. Sins are knowingly doing acting wrong while the angels cannot act wrong and sin. Angels do mistakes in their way of thinking but they can't do mistakes while they do actions ,in the sense, they don't have ability to execute their mistaken thought patterns in to actions.  But jinns and humans can do mistakes in their actions as well as thinkingstoo. This is what I understood from Quran and various ahadiths.wallahu 'alam.

Answer (score -2):

According to the Hebrews there is only one malaikah that is reported as being female. Her job is to take care of babies. We can assume that if there is one there is probably more.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lailah

"Lailah chooses a soul from the Garden of Eden and commands it to enter the embryo. Lailah watches over the development in the womb and shows the rewards and punishments available to the individual."

Comment: Is Lallah part of Islam? (The Wikipedia article says she's from Jewish mythology.)

Comment: This site is about Islam and not Judaism. Please give answers according to the Islamic point of view using Islamic sources, you may mention the Jewish point of view as complementary information where it makes sense.